# No CSS Highlighting and Completion in Intellij

Tags: css, intellij-idea

Somehow I don't get any highlighting and code completion in Intellij IDEA. Even though on the website they advertise highlighting and code completion: [JetBrains Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/editors/html_css_editor.jsp?ide=idea). HTML on the other hand works.

Is there an option to set or is it just not possible in the Community Edition?

This is the way it looks for me in the .css file

[image: Intellij CSS File Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, CSS support is only available in the Ultimate Edition. Check out the [Jetbrains feature comparison page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: Thanks! You can't have everything :/

Comment: As suggested by that very page, there should be (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu2gp.png). The only mention to CSS is made equally for Ultimate and Community editions

Comment: @CiroGarcía - this answer is nearly 8-years old and probably out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can get CSS syntax highlighting in IntelliJ Community Edition via [TextMate Bundles](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7221-textmate-bundles) plugin. The plugin is built-in in modern versions of IDEA and has built-in CSS bundle but to make it work you have to remove CSS from `Recognized File Types`:

- Go to `Settings > Editor > File Types > CSS (syntax highlighting only)`
- Remove `*.css` from `File name patterns`
  [image: Settings > Editor > File Types > CSS (syntax highlighting only)]

Before:
[image: Default CSS syntax highlighting in IntelliJ Community Edition]

After:
[image: TextMate syntax highlighting for CSS in IntelliJ Community Edition]